# tortoise SVN remove project and start again

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The other day I had posted about using SVN switch and got the answer I needed. In a nut shell the company I work for added two more teams ( over seas ) and the svn has become a night mare. I tried switching to their branch to test something for them and although it worked we have has some problems since then. I have worked everything pout but cannot get my svn to be the same as theirs. I have tried svn->clean, deleting and pull in the directories again, nothing has worked. What I want to do is to delete the project and just run a new checkout to start fresh. Within the project there are three directories. Can I remove just one of these, the main one ( we can call it main_dir ) and then pull it back in? Seems simple enough but this mess is far from simple at this point.

If this is possible, do I just right click svn->delete  on main_dir? Then how do I pull it back in?

One thing to consider. I have not committed some of the things I tried so I want to remove the changes I have made so it seems like I have nothing to commit which I think erasing this will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to make everything clear, why do you want to only delete and checkout one of the three directories? Why don't you restart from scratch?

Anyway, don't do SVN delete: this means that you want to make SVN delete the files at the next commit. What you need to do is just delete the files from your disk, and do a fresh checkout. A regular file delete is thus what you want.

Have you considered reading the freely available, and really simple to read [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)? Because it seems to me that you have problems only because you don't understand the basic functionality of SVN (like  deleting a file).

Comment: I am without a doubt new to this depth of SVN. I have always used it but only to keep versions straight. I will read this book and continue to learn, thanks for sending the link. If I delete, will that eliminate the changes I have ready for committing? I assume yes. So just delete like a normal directory then right click checkout?

Comment: If you delete files from your disk, the files won't be on your disk anymore.